# how to solve feign.RetryableException: connect timed out executing

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, microservices, spring-annotations

[error image feign-client error test enviroment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skJE5.png)

The code work correctly in localhost connection.

**In test enviroment don't work.**

I have microservices that run in the cloud.
I tried to add in the application.properties of NewsService:

- `feign.client.config.default.connectTimeout=160000000`
- `feign.client.config.default.readTimeout=160000000`

But not work.

It is as if it did not reach notification-service from the feign-client call.

**Locally on other calls I received this error and I changed the type of connection: from ethernet cable to router with the phone. Since the environment is in the cloud, I cannot solve it like this.**

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by knocking down and retiring on the pods: service-registry, gatway-service, news-service and notification-service.

*The environment is now cleaner*